# Android Studio crash when I declare my CalenderView

Tags: java, android, calendarview

A really simple application that has fragments, I am having an activity that holds a CalendarView that opens up from a side navigation drawer. When you open the "logs" fragment, it'll send you to the CalendarActivity for you to choose a date you want to log information on. However, the application crashes when you do this, I found out if you remove the line "logCalendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.logCalendar);" it won't crash, but obviously I now can't use the calendar to get a date.

Does anyone know why it's crashing, or any other solutions that provide the same solution to what I want to achieve.

Thanks.

**CalendarActivity class**

```
public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "CalendarActivity";

    private CalendarView logCalendar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
        logCalendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.logCalendar);

        logCalendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date =  dayOfMonth + "/" + month +"/" + year;
                Log.d(TAG, "onSelectedDayChange: date:" + date);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Class that opens the CalenderActivity class**

```
    private TextView currentDate;
    private Button dateButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logs, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        currentDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.currentDate);
        dateButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dateButton);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CalendarActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**My Logcat**

```
2020-12-20 16:45:53.987 28316-28316/com.example.co3201weighttrainingapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.co3201weighttrainingapplication, PID: 28316
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView cannot be cast to android.widget.CalendarView
        at com.example.co3201weighttrainingapplication.LogsFragment.onViewCreated(LogsFragment.java:48)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Please add your logcat here

Comment: `2020-12-20 16:18:53.237 26375-26375/com.example.co3201weighttrainingapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.co3201weighttrainingapplication, PID: 26375
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView cannot be cast to android.widget.CalendarView
        at com.example.co3201weighttrainingapplication.LogsFragment.onViewCreated(LogsFragment.java:46)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)
`

Comment: also posted logcat on the  main post, so its easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the logcat you have posted explains the error itself. see this line :-
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView cannot be cast to android.widget.CalendarView`.

It looks like you have imported `android` native `calendarView` instead of your `material calendar view`. Check your `imports` in your `CalendarActivity class` and you might find something like this :- `import android.widget.CalendarView;` remove that and change it to `import com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView;`. I am assuming you are using `applandeo` material calendar view from [this](https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View) site.